# How implement tarai in guile

Tags: guile

I now would like to run tarai, which reads in Prolog as follows. A test case would be to run `?- tarai(12,6,0,X)`. This is quite a hard test case, for example GNU Prolog crashes with this test case.

```
tarai(X, Y, Z, R) :- 
    X > Y -> 
        X1 is max(0,X-1), tarai(X1, Y, Z, Rx),
        Y1 is max(0,Y-1), tarai(Y1, Z, X, Ry),
        Z1 is max(0,Z-1), tarai(Z1, X, Y, Rz),
        tarai(Rx, Ry, Rz, R); 
    R = Y.
```

I am mostly interested whether the test case can be run over a fully declarative version of some miniKanren code for tarai. Optionally I would be interested in running some test cases backwards.

I am a little bit at loss. I managed to install guile, a scheme variant, and can run the [miniKanren](https://github.com/jasonhemann/microKanren) test cases successfully. But miniKanren has no integer numbers, so what could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this algorithm only has one solution if it's exists and is deterministic. You may pass scheme variables as x,y,z directly to the kanren tarai function, there is no unification for those hence implementing the logic for X,Y,Z can be done without kanren variables. The R values however needs to be logic variables and you need to get the bounded values in the tarai(Rx,Ry,Rz,R) form e.g. lookup the value of Rx,Ry,Rz and feed those into the tarai function. Also you need to make sure that this form is executed after the first three forms has finished (which is easy to do because there is no pure multiple choices) so that you know that Rx,Ry,Rz is bounded. Also note that this algorithm might depend on execution order in order to be executed efficiently but again the determinism means that this point is straightforward to satisfy. Note that A -> B ; C translates here simply to schemes (if A B C) because A = X > Y is deterministic. So the code could look something like this in pseudocode

```
(define (tarai x y z r)
  (lambda ()
    (fresh (rx ry rz)
       (if (> x y)
           (conda
             ( (conda ((tarai (- x 1) y z rx) 
                       (tarai (- y 1) z x ry)
                       (tarai (- z 1) x y rz)))
               (project (rx ry rz) (tarai rx ry rz r))))
           (== r y)))))
```

Comment: im on phone this weekend so just short answers. no the prolog code is not reversable as well. but if you want reversability you need to guard each clause with a less than, and greater than or equal. After this you need a wsy to constraint variables and do arithmetics with variables. in prolog you would do this with something like with a constaint solver like  clpfd or whats it called and perhaps numbers.scm will provide the same.

Comment: If you dont have max and min you can dived the cases using guards x > 0 and x=0

Comment: If you don't have conda, try use conde in the above example

Answer (score 0):

The question was refrased to ask for how to implement a more general version of the tarai function in the prolog spec that allows variables in x,y,z fields. The technique here can be implemented in prolog with e.g. clpfd finite domain solver and something similar is needed for kanren (se comment discussions above e.g. the reference to numbers.scm). The key thing is to nuke -> and use guards for all cases and we will assume that operators >o =o <=o is all defined for variables (e.g. for var X,  X > 0 will constrain X to be values 1,2,3,...). Also we will asume that '-o' is defined for variables as well of this kind using interval arithmetics constraints via a special 'iso'. Using this we can define tarai as the code below (this can be simplified if max and min is also defined as constraints but here we implement those via inequalities and a dived of cases in stead).

```
(define (taray x y z w)
  (lambda ()         
    (conde ((<o x y) 
            (fresh (rx ry rz)
              (conde
               ((conde 
                  ((>o x 0) 
                   (fresh (xx) 
                     (conde
                       ((iso xx (-o x 1)) 
                        (tarai xx y z rx)))))
                  ((== x 0) (tarai 0 y z rx)))
                (conde 
                  ((>o y 0) 
                   (fresh (yy) 
                     (conde
                       ((iso yy (-o y 1)) 
                        (tarai yy z x ry)))))
                  ((== y 0) (tarai 0 z x ry)))
                (conde 
                  ((>o z 0) 
                   (fresh (zz) 
                     (conde
                       ((iso zz (-o z 1)) 
                        (tarai zz x y rz)))))
                  ((== z 0) (tarai 0 x y r<)))
                (tarai rx ry rz r)))))
            ((>=o x y) (== x y))))))
```

Comment: I can add an o if you like to really mark that those are of an 'o kind

Comment: I don't have a link to number.scm atm because it is stoped by the firewall. I use a hypothetic constraint library e.g. a good one should support those like clpfd

Comment: Also note that it would be wise to be able to introduce constraints with an iso construct just as in clpfd.

Comment: To allow x or y or z or w to be variables you need  a finite domain solver for minikanren which you need to code yourself as I can't find such a library on the net, if x,y,z, is bounded you can just use my first version. I was hoping for your quest that inequalties was defined in numbers.scm, but it just looks like a lib for the usual numerics done in the good book 'reasoned schemer' from your description. Btw I give back not for the bounty but for giving back to community, SE is a fantastic source.

Comment: this was not correct previously, much simpler if one can use max

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of [guile-log](https://gitlab.com/gule-log/guile-log) a logic programming environment on guile scheme that has both minikanren constructs and prolog constructs and one can mix them. It also has a clpfd library ported so here you can do the following (unfourtunately atm it does not work (a bug i'm working on)). Assume that clpfd is imported. (,, ;; is interleaving kanren like ops). Replacing ,, with , and ;; with ; you get code that can run on for example swi prolog using the clpfd library.

```
tarai(X,Y,Z,W) :-
 (
   X #> Y , 
   (
     (
       ((X #> 0 , XX #= X - 1, tarai(XX,Y,Z,RX)) ;;
        (X  = 0 , tarai(0,Y,Z,RX))) ,,
       ((Y #> 0 , YY #= Y - 1, tarai(YY,Z,X,RY)) ;;
        (Y =  0 , tarai(0,Z,X,RY))) ,,
       ((Z #> 0 , ZZ #= Z - 1, tarai(ZZ,X,Y,RZ)) ;;
        (Z =  0 , tarai(0,X,Y,RZ)))
     ) ,,
     tarai(RX,TY,RZ,R)
   )
 ) ;;
 (X #=< Y, R=Y).
```

Comment: It's good to highlight different ideas and syntaxes in my personal opinion

Comment: note that you can change ,, to , and ;; to ; and run the code on swi prolog but then you don't get the guarrantrees that minikanren has against infinite recursion.

Comment: depth first search can lead to infinites in some cases and the great thing with minikanren is that you can code and know that if there is a solution you will eventually find it unless the memory is not enough. But there is not so much intelligence in selecting the search strategies and it can be wise to use other methods to wisely guide the search. This is probably what you see when you run tarai. One thing to look for is memoization that can speed up things.

Comment: Maybe one magnitude slower. One has to run it to know for sure though. Guile's compiler is sloooow though. 15minutes to compile clpfd.

Comment: I added a deterministic answer with timings in the guile-log scheme macro interface

Comment: I can unerstand that the search is very deep and blows the variable stack easilly not easy and My limit on the number of variables blows with this deterministic code

Comment: a bug, I'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

To do the deterministic verison in guile-log scheme macro interface [see links on this site](https://c-lambda.se/guile-log) you can implement it with memoization as (without memoization the solution blows the variable stack on guile-log)

```
(define tarai 
  (memo 
    (<lambda> (x y z r) 
       (if (> x y) 
           (<var> (rx ry rz) 
              (<and> 
                 (tarai (max (- x 1) 0) y z rx) 
                 (tarai (max (- y 1) 0) z x ry) 
                 (tarai (max (- z 1) 0) x y rz) 
                 (tarai (<lookup> rx) (<lookup> ry) (<lookup> rz) r))) 
           (<=> r y)))))

scheme@(guile-user)> ,time (<run> 1 (r) (tarai 12 6 0 r))
$13 = (12)
;; 0.293411s real time, 0.290711s run time.  0.000000s spent in GC.
scheme@(guile-user)>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191862/discussion-on-answer-by-stefan-how-implement-tarai-in-guile).

Answer (score 0):

I tried running for example tarai(12,X,0,12) with clpfd, but it's to complex for it. And memoizing does not work with attributed variables for swipl. So the best solution atm that I can find is to use the deterministic memoized tarai with something like

```
tarai2(X,Y,Z,W) :-
  (var(X)->between(0,20,X);true),
  (var(Y)->between(0,20,Y);true),
  (var(z)->between(0,20,Z);true),
  tarai(X,Y,Z,W).
```

then all solutions Y,Z in that range with tarai2(12,Y,Z,12) can easilly be found.

Comment: ask me to delete posts later and we can clean up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slow implementation that is declarative and uses [numbers.scm](https://github.com/miniKanren/miniKanren/blob/master/numbers.scm) (as suggested by the author of the question) and minkanren.

```
(load "minkanren.scm)
(load "numbers.scm")

(define one  (build-num 1))
(define zero (build-num 0))
(define (tarai x y z r)
    (conde
        ((<=o x y) (== r y))
        ((<o y x)
         (fresh (rx ry rz)
          (conde
           ((fresh (xx)
            (conde
             ((<o zero x) (minuso x one xx) (tarai xx y z rx))
             ((== zero x) (tarai zero y z rx))))
           (fresh (yy)
            (conde
             ((<o zero y) (minuso y one yy) (tarai yy z x ry))
             ((== zero y) (tarai zero z x ry))))
           (fresh (zz)
            (conde
             ((<o zero z) (minuso z one zz) (tarai zz x y rz))
             ((== zero z) (tarai zero x y rz))))
           (tarai rx ry rz r)))))))
```

If the derivation direction is reversed (so wee add numbers) we can still solve due to the declarative style,

```
tarai(4,2,Z,4):, (you need to make binaries of the number) will lead to
Y = [0, 1],
W = [0, 0, 1],
Z = [0, 0, 1],
X = [0, 0, 1].
```

And supposedly if tabling is added:

```
tarai(12,6,0,W):
Z = (),
X = [0, 0, 1, 1],
Y = [0, 1, 1],
W = [0, 0, 1, 1].
```

Comment: it looks like when you reverse the derivation it starts to count up elements and the number of cases explode and the search algorithm seam to take forever. Limiting the numers hinders this and it is a bit different from a between search because the search order is different.

Comment: yes it uses a little of the guile-log macros to enable the tabling essentially and make it runnable form the prolog prompt.

Comment: aha <o is interleaving meaning that they work differently than between

Comment: just tell me which one you want to remain and we can let it be like that!

Comment: your example is tarai(12,6,0,R), can be reversing if you could ask for tarai(12,Y,0,12) e.g. you can solve for any number of variables, this lead to multiple solutions. If you don't want tabling you have a minikanren solution in the above post quite easilly, which is declarative although it will use an interleaving between e.g. <o and friends and will not be based on a constraint solver.

Comment: Okey, I just rewrote it in kanren style, this will be what you are asked for. It is tested (perhaps a few paratheses wrong) to yield correct answers. But I suspect that when you run the test case it will blow. Shall I delete the rest of the posts?

Comment: This is fun, but we need to get a consistant store in this question. Let's just answer the question and defer questions  about tabling and how to solving this effectively to another question. AS it now stand people will get an example of how to code with minikanren I do think that references to guile-log is overkill, it's just my toy. For some fun have a look at http://c-lambda.se/interleaving-tables.html

Comment: If the solution is not a single point you need label or labeling. Guile uses the same source code by Triska as swipl.

Comment: The query: scheme@(guile-user) [4]> (run 1 (x) (tarai '(0 0 1 1) '(0 1 1) '() x)) runs already a minute, no result.

Comment: I got the result when using tabling in guile-log. For vanilla kanren you need to run smaller cases

Comment: Note you will have the same search space with kanren, as with the prolog version just that the kanren search will be much much slower due to 1) general slower execution mechansim, 2) keeping an assoc that grows quite a bit of the variable bindings.

Comment: maybe https://github.com/webyrd/tabling kan help you, i can't open this file atm.

Comment: Ok, I clarified your answer, and added that tabling is assumed for the second example. If I have time, I will also check whether the first example works, i.e. tarai(4,2,Z,4).